# WP Query - Order by metavalue and keep other posts

Tags: php, wordpress

Can't figure out this problem.
 **Goal:** I want to show **all posts** and order them by a post meta *value*, but not all posts have that meta *key*.

**Problem:** Not all posts are shown, only the ones that have that meta key (and meta value).

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'meta_key'       => 'post_custom_field_1',
'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
'order'   => 'ASC',
'paged' => $paged,'post_type' => 'post' );
```

**Question:** How can I show all posts and sort them by a meta_key? Posts that have the meta_key are shown first and ordered by name and posts that don't have the meta_key follow and are sorted by title.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use EXISTS for compare. There are plenty of examples [in the docs for WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters), you can adapt it to your case:

```
function orderby_fieldifexists($orderby) {
    return "mt1.post_id IS NOT NULL DESC, wp_postmeta.meta_value ASC";
}

add_filter("posts_orderby", "orderby_fieldifexists", 10, 1);

$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'meta_query' => array(
            "relation" => "or",
            'custom_field_value' => array(
                'key' => 'post_custom_field_1',
            ), 
            'custom_field' => array(
                'key' => 'post_custom_field_1',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
        'orderby' => array( 
            'custom_field' => 'ASC'
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
    )
);
```

I've initially had a simpler version in here, but then remembered that it would be silly to sort numerically if some values will be NULL. This version will find all posts, but get the value as well, and sort descending on "does it exist?" and then ascending on the actual values, so a post with a custom field value of -1 will be listed before those without that custom field value.

Comment: Thanks, this works but does not show all posts that don't have that meta key. I tried to add a general key as well like _wp_page_template. This works but the ordering gets messed up. It should show first the posts that have the meta key and order them from A to Z and then show all other posts and order them also in a certain way.

Comment: So it shows the custom_field_general (which is now _wp_page_template) first, and they should come after post_custom_field_1. All the other stuff works :). So it's ASC based on post_custom_field_1 but all posts with an empty post_custom_field_1 but that have custom_field_general are now before post_custom_field_1 and should be listed after all posts that have post_custom_field_1

Comment: You're right of course, EXISTS should be NOT EXISTS. Also, I've gone for adding a custom orderby SQL cause. You'll want to remove that filter after running that query so it doesn't interfere with other queries. See the edited answer.

Comment: Extremely awesome! This works. Got 1 problem left, what if a meta key exists but the meta value is empty. It should be handled as if there is no meta key at all, is this possible? At this point the post will be the first post to show while it should be part of the posts that don't have that meta key.

Comment: Sure. The `mt1.post_id IS NOT NULL DESC` part moves those with NULL to the bottom, just add a condition, and make it `mt1.post_id IS NOT NULL AND wp_postmeta.meta_value != '' DESC`. Conditions will evaluate to 1 or 0, and you can use AND and OR in them.